# Placing markers on a map with data from .sdf database

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a .sdf database with three main columns: `customer_name`, `lat` and `lon`.
I want to iterate through the rows of the table and use the information for the markers.
The issue is that the map is generating fine, but the markers aren't being placed on the map.

This is what I have so far..

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("Contracts");
    var query = "SELECT customer_name, lat, lon FROM Contracts ORDER BY customer_name";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        initalise();
    });

    function initalise() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.007227, -0.719798),
            zoom: 200,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementId("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
</script>

@foreach(var row in db.Query(query)) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var mark = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mark,
            map: map,
            title: @row.cusomter_name
        });
    </script>
}

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 640px; height: 480px;"></div>
```

The database columns have the attributes of `nvarchar(100)`, `float`, `float` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is invalid, aren't you getting a JS error?  The `map` variable is local to your initalise function (which is missing a closing `}`).  So when you try to reference it later on, it can't access it.  You're badly nesting your function with the `<script> ... </script>` tags.

Try this instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    initalise();
});

function initalise() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.007227, -0.719798),
        zoom: 200,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementId("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

    @foreach(var row in db.Query(query)) {
        var mark = new google.maps.LatLng(@row.lat, @row.lon);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mark,
            map: map,
            title: @row.customer_name
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If `row` contains customer name, latitude and longitude then `mark` should be changed to use `@row.lat` and `@row.lon`?

Comment: @AntoJurković good point, I hadn't noticed that `lat` and `lon` were undefined.  Will update my answer

Comment: Tried your code and received 11 build errors. All of them having to do with the syntax, either missing a `)` `;` or `,`. Although it only appears to be with the `@foreach` chunk. Any suggestions?

Comment: what's your server-side language?  You may need to create a global JS variable which is just an array of your contracts data that you then loop over within your initialize function